# Why are some of my wheels bugging out in rendered view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-pPjlI2Z0z9pbouFgKwVyVrHNFtBp-np/view?usp=sharing

This is what I'm getting on 3/4 wheels on my model in rendered view.
[image: This is what I'm getting on 3/4 wheels on my model in rendered view.]

This is what its supposed to look like in viewport shading
[image: This is what its supposed to look like in viewport shading]

I don't know where I've gone wrong with this.

Comment: don't know why my pic descriptions didn't post. The top pic is rendered view (cycles) and the bottom is viewport shading and how it was origianlly textured

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I re-done the problem face of the wheel and found overlapping geometry, so presume that was the problem as all fixed now!